# How to pass state to defaultValue of select form in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I need to pass state to defaultValue props in select form. I'm using Ant.design to create form elements. When i pass state to defaultValue props directly, the value state will return undefined. So, i create `getDefaultSOFValue()` to retrieve value from request and pass it to state. Here my components code:

**SelectInput.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Select } from 'antd'
import './SelectInput.css'

function SelectInput(props) {
    return(
        <Select defaultValue={props.defaultValue} value={props.value} onChange={props.onChange} placeholder={props.placeholderSelect} style={props.styleSelect}>
            {props.valueSelect}
        </Select>
    )
}

export default SelectInput
```

**Form.js**

```
import SelectInput from '../../../components/Form/Select/OrdinarySelect/SelectInput'
import { Select } from 'antd'
import 'antd/dist/antd.css'
import axios from 'axios'

class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.getAccountName = this.getAccountName.bind(this)
        this.getDefaultSOFValue = this.getDefaultSOFValue.bind(this)
        this.handleSOFChange = this.handleSOFChange.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            inputSOF: '',
            inputSOFDefaultValue: [],
            valueSOF: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        // Fetch formInputData API 
        let formInputDataUrl = 'https://localhost:8000/formInputData'
        let data = {
            'inputPage': 'testInput'
        }

        axios.post(formInputDataUrl, data)
        .then(res => {
            // Assign "sof account" object to new Array.
            let copyOfSoffAll = {
                0: res.data.sofManagamentServiceResponse.sofAll.ccaccountList[1],
                1: res.data.sofManagamentServiceResponse.sofAll.caaccountList[0], 
                2: res.data.sofManagamentServiceResponse.sofAll.caaccountList[1],
                3: res.data.sofManagamentServiceResponse.sofAll.saaccountList[3]
            }
            this.setState({
                inputSOFDefaultValue: res.data.sofManagamentServiceResponse.sofAll.ccaccountList[1],
                inputSOF: copyOfSoffAll,
            })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))

    }

    getDefaultSOFValue(){
        // this function used for get defaultValue and pass it to defaultValue prop in Select
    }

    getAccountName(){
        return Object.values(this.state.inputSOF).map((value, index) => {
            return <Option key={index} value={ value.accountBalance } >{ value.accountName } <br /> { value.accountNumber }</Option>
        }) 
    }

    handleSOFChange(value){
        this.setState({
            valueSOF: value
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                <div className='container'>
                    <SelectInput 
                       defaultValue={ this.getDefaultSOFValue() }
                       valueSelect={ this.getAccountName() } 
                       styleSelect={{ width: '60%' }}
                       onChange={this.handleSOFChange}
                     />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Form
```

Comment: You don't need to set default value on [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) only on [uncontrolled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values)

Comment: @HMR i've replace defaultValue with value but this is don't solve my problem.

Comment: Did you try `value={props.value||someDefaultValue}` I assume you are rendering the component when `props.value` is undefined initially. When you render a controlled component then you must give it a value so either make sure the value prop is set in the component or the parent that provides the value prop.

Comment: this is work for return the false condition, but how to return the true ones?

Comment: you could check if props.value is undefined and then use the default:  `const {value=theDefailt}=props`.

Comment: Would you explain me where must i put this code?